# Wordpress URLs not returning 404 Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, seo

I need some help with WordPress following a hack.

I've cleaned the hack completely and Google has removed the "*This site may be hacked*" flag.

The hack submitted a plethora of URLs to Google that contain a random string at the end of each valid URL. These show as Japanese links in google search.

There are URLs listed that show as:

```
www.example.co.uk/?WGlaVUdsVVNHUnNXVzFzY2xwVE1YbFphVGg1VFZSSmVFOVVTVFZQUjJNOWNFUT14b0g
```

If I click the link, it shows the sites correct homepage rather than showing a 404 page.

If I go to `www.example.co.uk/thispagedoesnotesist` it displays the 404 error just fine.

Is there a way I can get pages with these random URL strings to show a 404 error?

Any help or advice would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force URLs that contain a long random query string to a 404 with something like the following mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess`. This needs to go *before* your existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\w{30,}$
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404,L]
```

A request for the document root (home page) that contains a query string of 30 or more letters/digits then serve a 404.

However, if these are *Japanese* characters in the URL (as opposed to a-z as in your example) then the above might not match, so try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^=]{30,}$
```

Which matches all chars except `=`.

**UPDATE:** To match an *optional* `=` at the end then you can include `=?` before the `$` in the above regex. For example `^\w{30,}=?$` or `^[^=]{30,}=?$`.

If you don't use query strings at all then you could change the `RewriteCond` directive to the following, which matches *any* query string (that is at least 1 character).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```

Comment: Sir, you are amazing. This is exactly what i needed!! Thank you!

One last question. I noticed that if the URL ends with an = the URL is not redirected to the 404 page. Is there any way to include URLs with the = at the end?

Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer with regards to matching an optional `=` at the end.

Comment: That's great. Thank You so much.

Could this work for other random characters too? I've noticed that URL's with % in them are not being redirected to 404.

I'd redirect all queries, but i think the Contact Form 7 plugin uses a query when the form submit button is pressed.

Thanks again for all your time. It's really appreciated.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Please ignore the above. I changed the condition to match the second one you mentioned and then added the extra for the =

Working Perfectly :)

Comment: Ok. I thought it was working OK. It appears not. 

Some of the URLs contain '=%' just before the end of the string. 

An example is: '/?VXpNZWxwaFIyaHJURmhDYUdOdVVucE1lbEUwVFVSamVXVm5QVDFMVUE9PXVReA=%3D'

Any other URL with just alphanumerics or the = is fine.

Sorry for being a pain!

Comment: It might be sufficient just to remove the end of string anchor (and comma), ie. `^[^=]{30}` - that simply matches any query string that _starts with_ 30 non `=` chars, followed by anything.

Comment: Sir, if i could buy you a drink, i would. Thank you so much for all your help! Everything working as required.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that those links point to your home page with parameters. Those random strings of text are not passed as segments of url nor pages since they are preceded with `?`.

There isn't a whole lot you can do. If I were in your place I would just report the links and request their removal from Google's side. Don't worry about it on your end.