# numbers after wordpress urls not showing 404

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, redirect, permalinks

I just notice a bug in my WordPress sites when I am adding any number after a blog post or page URL it's not showing any 404 error or its just a valid page

like I have a site

https://www.gryffin.com/ so if I visiting this URL https://www.gryffin.com/features/ and adding any number after this URL https://www.gryffin.com/features/98989 like this it should show the error of page not exist but it's not giving this error I check other WordPress sites have the same issue I think its not good on SEO point of view can anybody give me solution of it.

Comment: [You can found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536414/wordpress-urls-not-returning-404-pages)

Comment: I also notice this, but it doesn't matter if you are using wordpress or any other platform i had checked on shopify also, if you add any number to end of link it will not show 404 page,but if you add random character it will show you 404. why it is happening? do any one has answer for this, i seriously want to know why it is happening?